# Check Domain & Show Banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently working in a CMS that lets me share assets across different domains.

I'm trying to save time by sharing some of the work across several sites.  I've never done this before so I was wondering if somebody could help me.

What I'm trying to do is:

if domain is http://www.domain1.com addClass="bg1"

if domain is http://www.domain2.com addClass="bg2"

This will essentially add a class which changes the background image of a div to show the correct banner

Thanks!!

Comment: This is best accomplished by whatever your backend server is running (e.g. PHP, Python, Java, ASP, etc.).  Do you have control of the server codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain1.com') {
        $('#my-banner').addClass('bg1').removeClass('bg2');
    } else if (window.location.hostname == 'www.domain2.com') {
        $('#my-banner').addClass('bg2').removeClass('bg1');
    }
});
```

Not tested, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Basically yes, but why not use a `switch (document.location.hostname)` rather than reevaluating repeatedly?

Comment: @DavidThomas Because that's the first thing that popped into my mind and I don't care about micro optimization as long as it's not necessary.

Comment: It's not just a micro-optimisation, it also reduces the scope of error by mistyping the same thing repeatedly. But it's your answer, and your call.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `location` and `host` or `hostname` like this :

JS :

```
if(location.host == 'domain1.com'){
    // Some Stuff
}else if(location.host == 'domain2.com'){
    // Some Stuff
}
```

You can type `location` in developer console and see all object property